# How to show that an upper bound is $\frac{2-b}{1-b}\mathbb E [Y^{b}]$ exists for the following integral

Tags: probability, inequality, expected-value

Consider for $b \in (0,1)$ and two continuous positive random variables $X$ and $Y$, that we have the following inequalities already given:

$$1.\; \mathbb E [X^{b}] \leq \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}b x ^{b-1}\left(\mathbb P(X\geq  x, Y\leq x)+\mathbb P(Y>x)\right)dx\\ 2. \; \mathbb P(X\geq  x, Y\leq x)\leq \frac{1}{x}\mathbb E[Y\land x]$$

I want to show that:
$$ \mathbb E [X^{b}] \leq \frac{2-b}{1-b}\mathbb E [Y^{b}]$$

My ideas so far:

$$ \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}b x ^{b-1}\left(\mathbb P(X\geq  x, Y\leq x)+\mathbb P(Y>x)\right)dx\leq \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}b x ^{b-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\mathbb E[Y\land x]+\mathbb P(Y>x)\right)dx\\=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}b x ^{b-2}\mathbb E[Y\land x]dx+\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}b x ^{b-1}\mathbb P(Y>x)dx$$

Note that the second term can be written as $\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}b x ^{b-1}\mathbb P(Y>x)dx=\mathbb E[Y^{b}]$

But I am having trouble computing the first term $\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}b x ^{b-2}\mathbb E[Y\land x]dx$. Any ideas?

Comment: It remains to show $\int_0^\infty x^{b-2}\Bbb E[Y\land x]\,dx\le\Bbb E[Y^b]/(b(b-1))$ so I'm guessing we'll need to integrate by parts twice (which incidentally cancels out $b(b-1)$ on the denominator).